Getting redirect_uri for microsoft azure pipelines
I've been working on a project that requires a Android Microsoft Authentication Library redirect_uri, but I am not sure how to get it when building using azure pipelines.
Currently I am building all my projects locally using android studio, but I would like to use microsoft pipelines to build the project whenever I push to main. My app is using the Android Microsoft Authentication Library, so I generated a MSAL config file with a redirect_uri for my computer. The issue is, azure pipelines run on another computer, which means they require another redirect_uri. How can I get it?
I know what needs to happen to get a redirect_uri, I can get the signature hash easily. From there I can get a redirect_uri going through the web portal, but this is not good for consistent behaviour since there's no guarantee the computer will stay the same between builds. I also know with scripting files I can replace the redirect_uri before building. The only part which is missing is remotely getting redirect_uri.
